# locally installed grunt, "grunt exec:blank" fails with "/bin/sh: grunt: command not found"

Tags: magento2, grunt

I am hosted at Nexcess and tried to implement Grunt to assist with LESS development. I followed the Magento 2 docs for installing grunt. NodeJS 10.10.0 is installed.

The first deviation from the instructions has to do with how grunt, grunt-cli, and lessc were installed. The instructions say to install globally, with the -g parameter, but as this is shared hosting, that's not possible.

So instead I install locally to ~/public_html/. This creates a node_modules folder. This was followed up with npm install and npm update. I can now run grunt with its full path from the magento public_html folder, but I get an error:

`~/public_html/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt exec:blank`

```
 [public_html]$ ./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt exec:blank
Running "exec:blank" (exec) task
  /bin/sh: grunt: command not found
  Exited with code: 127.
  Error executing child process: Error: Process exited with code 127.
Warning: Task "exec:blank" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Running the clean: or less: commands both work on the blank theme. Only exec fails.. That is, I should say.. clean:blank works while less:blank results in some additional messages that I am not sure how to explain:

```
 public_html]$ ./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt less:ms
Running "less:ms" (less) task
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/MS/theme-frontend-ms/en_US/css/styles-m.css not written because no source files were found.
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/MS/theme-frontend-ms/en_US/css/styles-l.css not written because no source files were found.
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/MS/theme-frontend-ms/en_US/css/email.css not written because no source files were found.
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/MS/theme-frontend-ms/en_US/css/email-inline.css not written because no source files were found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grunt `exec` command expects `grunt` to be in `$PATH`. Since the node_modules `bin` path isn't commonly included in the `$PATH` variable, that would explain this issue. There's more than one way to solve this problem:

- Install grunt-cli globally: https://gruntjs.com/getting-started#installing-the-cli
- Make the locally-installed grunt-cli accessible in your path: `PATH=./node_modules/.bin:$PATH`. This can be done multiple ways:

  - on a per-command basis: `PATH=... ./node_modules/.bin/grunt <cmd>`
  - in a `.<shell>rc` file: `export PATH=./node_modules/.bin:$PATH`
  - in `/etc/profile` just the same way as the previous option
  - n.b. the two previous options will require you to update your current shell with the config file or start a new one
- Use [direnv](https://direnv.net/) to update your path only where necessary. The `.envrc` file can be added to your current project root directory, and `direnv allow` will update your current shell based on the contents of `.envrc`

Have fun!

P.S. here's where Magento generates the command to run grunt as a child process: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5/dev/tools/grunt/configs/combo.js#L17. Note that it doesn't specify a path to grunt, just assumes invoking `grunt` will work.